# DateTimePicker Value of Day VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker

I have DateTimepicker1 and DateTimePicker2 . I need to get the specific value of day from DT1 to DT2.

`ex. DT1 = Sept 27, 2013 and DT2 = Sept Oct 2, 2013`

i want to get the value 27,28,29,30,1,2 to integer

this is my code but only works in day 1 to 30.

```
 For mcount = DateTimePicker1.Value.Day To DateTimePicker2.Value.Day
    ' value = mcount
 Next
```

Can anyone help me in this?.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
For mcount = DateTimePicker1.Value To DateTimePicker2.Value
   value = mcount.Day
Next
```

Comment: this is the error : 'For' loop control variable cannot be of type 'Date' because the type does not support the required operators. ,,thats the logic but what or how to do it correctly.

Comment: Change to while loop:     Dim Date1 As Date = DateTimePicker1.Value 
    While Date1 <= DateTimePicker2.Value
        value = mcount.Day
        Date1 = Date1.AddDays(1)
    End While

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Post Solved!